# Help with ROS Navigation Stack Create2

Tags: ros, navigation, create2, move-base, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if anyone has had any experience running navigation (ROS Navigation Stack). I know that the base is fairly new, but I believe I have all of the applicable topics ready (/scan, /odom, /tf. /tf_static), but I am having trouble creating launch file to do all of these things to do SLAM and the navigation stack.

Also, does anyone know the roslaunch or rosrun command to start the navigation package to gain topics such as /move_base, /dwa_local_planner? I have done so before but have lost the command and am having a hard time finding it again.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS indigo, any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226255/help-with-ros-navigation-stack-create2/) by [millyjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/25909/millyjar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My suggestion would be to install the Turtlebot packages to see an example of how the Navigation Stack can be setup. In the [turtlebot_bringup](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_bringup) package they have the option to the set the base as the Create as well, which could be useful for you.

Specifically, look in the [turtlebot_navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation) package at the `amcl_demo.launch` and `gmapping_demo.launch` files to see how the nodes for `amcl`, `gmapping`, or `move_base` can be started. Also, if you look at the includes for the launch files and in the param folder you'll find examples for all the parameter settings for `amcl`, `gmapping`, and `move_base`.

You can follow the [Turtlebot Navigation Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo) for Navigation and Simulation for an example of how to use the above, and if you haven't already done so take a look at the [Navigation Stack Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) as well.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2016-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fj138696](https://answers.ros.org/users/30352/fj138696/) on 2017-05-17**:
Hi, [millyjar](http://answers.ros.org/users/25909/millyjar/)  I'd like to know if you have successfully run the the [turtle_navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation) using your iRobot create2 as suggested?
I am very new to ROS, and I am not sure if this package can support create2.thanks

**Comment by [doomrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40833/doomrobot/) on 2019-05-24**:
Did any one of the aspirants got navigation stack to run on create 2?